# Creating a generic class pool where you give the generic parameter and get a generic object that used that parameter

Tags: c#, generics, object-pooling, generic-type-argument

### Goal

I have a generic class `GenericClass<T>` and I want to pool instances.
I'm interested in seeing if I can get the syntax:

```
MyGenericPool = new GenericPool<GenericClass>();
// Or maybe it's MyGenericPool = new GenericPool<GenericClass<>>();

GenericClass<TGenericParam> GenericClassInstance =
    MyGenericPool.Get<TGenericParam>();
```

<sup>(My understanding of generics says, no I can't, don't be silly the syntax doesn't exist / wouldn't work, but I'm intested in what others think).</sup>

---

### Showing my workings

I'm a bit doubtful as from my understanding the types `GenericClass<string>` and `GenericClass<int>` aren't really related from the type system's point of view.

Now, I realise that I can get close, i.e.:

```
GenericClass<TGenericParam> GenericClassInstance =
    GenericPool.Get<GenericClass<TGenericParam>>();
```

and then have the `GenericPool` just store a `Dictionary<Type, ObjectPool<object>>` somewhere.
**I'm interested in seeing if I can avoid having to do that. I don't want to have to specify the generic type every time when, as the caller, i'm only changing the generic type parameter.** I'd also like to be able to enforce (compile time) that all objects going into my `GenericObjectPool<T>` are of a set generic type (`T<>`).

---

I think the problem stems from not being able to treat a generic type parameter as being generic its self. If I could do that (can I already??) then maybe something like the below might work:

```
public class GenericClassPool<TGeneric> where TGeneric : class<>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> objectPools = new Dictionary<Type, object>();


    private void EnsureObjectPoolExists<TGenericParam>()
    {
        if (!objectPools.ContainsKey(typeof(TGenericParam)))
        {
            objectPools.Add(typeof(TGenericParam), new ObjectPool<TGeneric<TGenericParam>>(() => Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TGeneric<TGenericParam>)) as TGeneric<TGenericParam>));
        }
    }

    private ObjectPool<TGeneric<TGenericParam>> GetPool<TGenericParam>()
    {
        EnsureObjectPoolExists<TGenericParam>();
        return (objectPools[typeof(TGenericParam)] as ObjectPool<TGeneric<TGenericParam>>);
    }

    public void Add<TTypeParam>(TGeneric<TGenericParam> obj)
    {
        EnsureObjectPoolExists<TTypeParam>();

        GetPool<TGenericParam>().Add(obj);
    }

    public TGeneric<TGenericParam> Get<TGenericParam>()
    {
        return GetPool<TGenericParam>().Get() as TGeneric<TGenericParam>;
    }
}
```

---

### Question

Can I get the syntax I want (at the top)? If not, how close can I get?

Comment: I got a bit lost while reading your post (it's lunchtime), so forgive me if this is misguided, but have you considered Reflection?

Comment: Reflection is what I first thought of too, but the problem with it might be that it's not strongly typed (doesn't allow expressing type contraints the way George wants) - it will require casting the result to `TGeneric<TGenericParam>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution / syntax you are trying to achieve doesn't work that way, because you can't use a generic type without its type parameters as the type parameter to another generic type.

However, you could achieve similar results with the following approach:

1. Create a base class for the class pool that requires you to supply the complete generic type
2. Create a derived class for the specific generic type

Something like that:

```
public class ObjectPool
{
    Dictionary<Type, object> _objectPool = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public void Add<TKey, TValue>(TValue value)
    {
        _objectPool.Add(typeof(TKey), value);
    }

    public TValue Get<TKey, TValue>() where TValue : class
    {
        object value;
        if(_objectPool.TryGetValue(typeof(TKey), out value))
            return value as TValue;
        return null;
    }
}

public class GenericClassPool : ObjectPool
{
    public void Add<TGenericParam>(GenericClass<TGenericParam> obj)
    {
        Add<TGenericParam, GenericClass<TGenericParam>>(obj);
    }

    public GenericClass<TGenericParam> Get<TGenericParam>()
    {
        return Get<TGenericParam, GenericClass<TGenericParam>>();
    }
}
```

Usage would then be like this:

```
var pool = new GenericClassPool();
pool.Add(new GenericClass<string> { Property = "String" });
pool.Add(new GenericClass<int> { Property  = 0 });

GenericClass<string> firstObject = pool.Get<string>();
GenericClass<int> secondObject = pool.Get<int>();
```

The draw back of this solution is that you would need to create one pool class for each generic type you want to pool, so you potentially will have a lot of `<className>Pool` classes deriving from `ObjectPool`.
To make this usable, all real code needs to be in the `ObjectPool` class and only code that supplies the generic parameters remains in the derived classes.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of figured it wasn't going to be possible. This is a good alternative although as you point out, it does have its downsides.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: Indeed, it has. But the main benefit of this solution is: After creating the derived class and the pool instance, usage is as desired - no need to specify `GenericClass<int>` in the call to `Get`. You could even create a live template that generates that derived class, because its always the same.

Comment: True, it's almost exactly what I'd want ideally. Your suggestion of using a template is good too. Could probably do something fancy with T4, giving it a list of generic class names and it producing C# code for pools of those generic classes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to share my own pool classes. They have a similar API to the other code posted but are a bit more developed and flexible, in my *totally biased opinion*.

Single type object pool:

```
/// <summary>
/// Allows code to operate on a Pool<T> without casting to an explicit generic type.
/// </summary>
public interface IPool
{
    Type ItemType { get; }
    void Return(object item);
}

/// <summary>
/// A pool of items of the same type.
/// 
/// Items are taken and then later returned to the pool (generally for reference types) to avoid allocations and
/// the resulting garbage generation.
/// 
/// Any pool must have a way to 'reset' returned items to a canonical state.
/// This class delegates that work to the allocator (literally, with a delegate) who probably knows more about the type being pooled.
/// </summary>    
public class Pool<T> : IPool
{
    public delegate T Create();
    public readonly Create HandleCreate;

    public delegate void Reset(ref T item);
    public readonly Reset HandleReset;

    private readonly List<T> _in;

#if !SHIPPING
    private readonly List<T> _out;
#endif

    public Type ItemType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof (T);   
        }            
    }

    public Pool(int initialCapacity, Create createMethod, Reset resetMethod)
    {
        HandleCreate = createMethod;
        HandleReset = resetMethod;

        _in = new List<T>(initialCapacity);            
        for (var i = 0; i < initialCapacity; i++)
        {
            _in.Add(HandleCreate());
        }
#if !SHIPPING
        _out = new List<T>();            
#endif
    }

    public T Get()
    {
        if (_in.Count == 0)
        {
            _in.Add(HandleCreate());
        }

        var item = _in.PopLast();
#if !SHIPPING
        _out.Add(item);
#endif
        return item;
    }

    public void Return( T item )
    {
        HandleReset(ref item);
#if !SHIPPING
        Debug.Assert(!_in.Contains(item), "Returning an Item we already have.");
        Debug.Assert(_out.Contains(item), "Returning an Item we never gave out.");
        _out.Remove(item);
#endif
        _in.Add(item);
    }

    public void Return( object item )
    {
        Return((T) item);
    }

#if !SHIPPING
    public void Validate()
    {
        Debug.Assert(_out.Count == 0, "An Item was not returned.");
    }
#endif
}
```

Next, a multi-type pool.

There is no difference between using this class or using multiple `Pool<T>` yourself. But in some situations using this class will make code look cleaner, ie. eliminating `if/else (type == foo)` blocks.

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a collection of pools for one or more object types.
/// </summary>
public class Pooler
{
    private readonly List<IPool> _pools;

    public Pooler()
    {
        _pools = new List<IPool>();
    }

    public void DefineType<T>(int initialCapacity, Pool<T>.Create createHandler, Pool<T>.Reset resetHandler)
    {
        var p = new Pool<T>(initialCapacity, createHandler, resetHandler);
        _pools.Add(p);
    }

    public T Get<T>()
    {
        var p = GetPool(typeof (T));
        if (p == null)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Pooler.Get<{0}>() failed; there is no pool for that type.", typeof(T)));

        return ((Pool<T>)p).Get();
    }

    public void Return(object item)
    {
        var p = GetPool(item.GetType());
        if (p == null)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Pooler.Get<{0}>() failed; there is no pool for that type.", item.GetType()));

        p.Return(item);            
    }

    private IPool GetPool(Type itemType)
    {
        foreach (var p in _pools)
        {
            if (p.ItemType == itemType)
            {
                return p;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

As far as 'not having to specify the type parameter every time you access the pool', I often declare a concrete pool for a specific type that is frequently used.

```
public class GameObjectPool : Pool<GameObject>
{   
   public GameObjectPool(int initialCapacity)
      :base(initialCapacity, CreateObject, ResetObject)
   {
   }

   private GameObject CreateObject()
   { ... }

   private GameObject ResetObject()
   { ... }
}
```

Then your code which was...

```
_pool = new Pool<GameObject>(10);
var obj = _pool.Get<GameObject>();
```

Can become...

```
_pool = new GameObjectPool(10);
var obj = _pool.Get();
```

Another option is...

```
using GameObjectPool=MyRootnamespace.Pool<GameObject>
```

Which can work if you have a ton of references to the pool, but they are all in the same code file.